# Opera browser not loading the js files

Tags: jquery, opera

I am doing a project in local host,

this is my host: `http://localhost:85/xxx/trunk/Webroot/task-1.html`

this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>task1</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.defaults.overrides.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        alert('hi')
    </script>
</head>
<body>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    </body>
</html>
```

but in the opera developer tool i just see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>task1</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"/>
</head>
</html>
```

here my rest of the js files not visible, as well i am not getting the alert message... what is wrong? how can i fix this?

rest of all browsers works fine.

Comment: Start by adding type to your script tags, and see if that solves it -> `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`

Comment: i tried, no luck. it's already deduct the jquery tool kit file right.

Comment: It's a simple structure, not much could go wrong with that one? Only other thing I can think of is closing the meta charset tag by adding a `/` at the end, or that you forgot to clear the cache in the browser.

Comment: cache cleared, no luck. as well added the '/' in to meta. not getting the linked files. apart from something need to config i believe, but i don't have any idea.

Comment: Does `main.js` contain `document.write()` statements? They may be overwriting the script tags. Are there any console error messages?

Comment: have you seen my code what i got, even there is no body tag at all...

Comment: Which version of opera you were using?

Comment: Have you checked the error console and/or tried to debug your content in Opera Dragonfly?

Comment: If you load http://localhost:85/xxx/trunk/Webroot/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js by pasting that URL in the URL field, does it load? If you make a page that only contains <iframe src="http://localhost:85/xxx/trunk/Webroot/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></iframe> and load it from http://localhost/ do you see the JS inside the IFRAME? (Please add http: in front of the URLs BTW, Stackoverflow seems to strip the protocol when making the URL clickable)